# BiometricPrompt Executor and/or callback was null

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I'm using BiometricPrompt from `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta02` for the authenticate process.
But i face very strange problem.

First time i call `biometricsPromt.authenticate()` everything works fine, the library shows me the screen depending what security method is set(pattern,fingerprint, password and etc…) then the callback is called and everything is good.

The problem is when i call `biometricsPromt.authenticate()` for the second time i got the error:

> E/DeviceCredentialHandler: onCreate: Executor and/or callback was
>   null!

*I'm passing executor and callback of course -> they are not null*

Does anyone face the same problem or have some idea what can be the problem?

This is how i'm creating the BiometricPromt

`

```
companion object {
        private val executor: Executor by lazy {
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        }

        fun showBiometricsPrompt(
            activity: FragmentActivity,
            callback: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback
        ): BiometricPrompt {
            val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.title_authentication))
                .setDescription(activity.getString(R.string.msg_authenticate_first))
                .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
                .build()

            val biometricPrompt =
                BiometricPrompt(
                    activity,
                    executor, callback
                )
            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
            return biometricPrompt
        }
```

`

And here is how i called:

`

```
BiometricsHelper.showBiometricsPrompt(
                this,
                object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                    override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)

                        showToastMsg(errString.toString())
                    }

                    override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                        super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                    }

                    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)

                    }
                })
```

`

Comment: Can you post the source code?

Comment: @MuhammadSaad Yes, I've edited the question

Comment: I am having this exact same issue in a legacy app, in a fragment. Did you only manage to fix it by finishing the activity?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a work around this problem, but not a complete fix.

You need to call `recreate()` after you finish doing whatever you set out to do after the authentication.

This will restart the activity and allow the biometric prompt to be shown again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is related to this line: .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)

If I change that to false, it works every time without re-creating the activity

Comment: Yes, but if you want to use it should re-create the activity

Comment: Yes buggy as always, they seem to be ignoring that flag when recreating the BiometricPrompt object.

Answer (score 0):

What device are you testing on? Can you file a bug on the public issuetracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=559537&template=1214425) with both

1. adb bugreport foo.zip
2. ideally a .zip of a sample app that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
private val executor: Executor by lazy {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
}
```

and replace your executor with:

```
ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity)
```